# What is the mapping between the property types and their editors in a SettingsPane?

Tags: java, gluon-mobile

`SettingsPane` can automatically select an editor for properties. In its doecs it says

> The SettingsPane control is designed to make it really easy for developers to present to end users a list of options that can be modified, using proper built-in editors according the type of those options.

I have 2 questions in this regard:

1. Which component is chosen for each property type? I saw that booleans have the right-left toggle, numbers have a text field, `ObjectProperty<Color>` has a color chooser (which on desktop pops out - i don't know what will happen on mobile?). What are the rest of the mappings?
2. When I try to have an enum property: `ObjectProperty<EnumType>` I get an error for no renderer. I would think that a combobox would be the default for choosing from a known number of enum constants, shouldn't it? I know I can make that happen with the editor factory myself but I wanted to ask about this anyway, maybe as a suggestion if i didn't make a mistake.

**Edit**

I'm looking again at the SettingPane example for custom editor: http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/4.3.7/com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/SettingsPane.html
and I'm noticing 2 problems:

1. In the example code of the checkbox editor see my comments:

   ```
   public class CheckBoxEditor implements OptionEditor<Boolean> {
       private final CheckBox checkBox;
       public CheckBoxEditor(Option<Boolean> option) {
          this.checkBox = new CheckBox();
          valueProperty().bindBidirectional(option.valueProperty());
       }} // only 1 }
       @Override public Node getEditor() { return checkBox; }
       @Override public final Property<Boolean> valueProperty() { return checkBox.selectedProperty(); }
       @Override public Boolean getValue() { return checkBox.isSelected(); }
       @Override public void setValue(Boolean value) { checkBox.setSelected(value); }
   // missing }
   ```
2. In the usage example:

   ```
   final Option<BooleanProperty> dateOption = new DefaultOption(MaterialDesignIcon.DATE_RANGE.graphic(),
          "Show Date", "Show the date", "Category", settings.showDateProperty(), true,
          option -> new CheckBoxEditor((Option<Boolean>) option));
   ```

the lambda gives me a compilation error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from CheckBoxEditor to OptionEditor<BooleanProperty>
```

and `option` is of type `Option<BooleanProperty>` and the cast is to `Option<Boolean>`. A mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default editors for a `SettingsPane` [control](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/latest/com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/SettingsPane.html) are:

- String: `TextField`.
- Numbers (byte and Byte, short and Short, int and Integer, long and Long, float and Float, double and Double, BigInteger, BigDecimal): `TextField` with a `TextFormatter` applied.
- Boolean: `ToggleButton`.
- LocalDate: `DatePicker`.
- Color/Paint: `ColorPicker`.
- Enums: `ComboBox`.

You can override this, by setting your own factory with `SettingsPane::setOptionEditorFactory`, but you will have to provide all the required editors.

Also you can override a particular editor, or you can add your own editor for a given type.

This is a sample of an `Enum` option:

```
enum OS { WINDOWS, MAC, LINUX, OTHER }

ObjectProperty<OS> os = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(OS.MAC);

Option<OS> OSOption = new DefaultOption(MaterialDesignIcon.LAPTOP.graphic(), "Operative System", 
            "Set the preferred OS", "Operative System", os, true);
```

[image]

Regarding the JavaDoc, yes, those are typos that need fixing. I've filed and issue on it.

About running the sample, it works for me as is. See the above pic, for the WiFi option:

```
final BooleanProperty wifi = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
final Option<BooleanProperty> wifiOption = new DefaultOption(MaterialDesignIcon.WIFI.graphic(), 
            "WiFi", "Set Wifi or Wire", "Devices", wifi, true, 
            option -> new CheckBoxEditor((Option<Boolean>) option));
```

Comment: After testing I found that the error for the enum in my second question happens when the value of the property is null, then this is printed `Error, no rendering options for: <option name>`. As for the lambda compilation error, i found out it happens if you make `DefaultOption` generic (`DefaultOption<>` or `DefaultOption<BooleanProperty>`). Not sure why.

Comment: For every property you need a way to render its value. You can define a converter if you need to. As for the generic, using `new DefaultOption<>` works fine if you use the default editor, but when adding the custom editor the types `BooleanProperty` and `Boolean` don't match, and you can't. It would work if the type for the Option was just `Boolean` (with `wifi.getValue()`), but then it wouldn't be observable.

Comment: Hey, can you have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46815240/dialog-causes-drag-done-events-to-not-propagate please?